# Distribution of a function

Tags: probability

Suppose $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Z=\frac{X}{1+X}$. Find $\Bbb E Z$ and $P(Z\le\Bbb EZ)$.

What I tried: for finding $\Bbb EZ$ I think first I should find the derivative of $Z$ and then solve $\Bbb EZ$ by the integral ranging from $0$ to $1$ of $dX/dZ$.

Comment: What is meant with $x\in U(0,1)$? That $x$ is a random variable having uniform distribution on interval $(0,1)$ maybe? If so then you should add that to your question. Also add your own efforts in order to avoid downvotes and closing.

Comment: Yes,thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @J.G. Unfortunately your edit just overlapped an edit of the OP in which efforts were shown.

Comment: @drhab Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Since$$\Bbb EZ=\int_0^1\frac{xdx}{1+x}=[x-\ln(1+x)]_0^1=1-\ln 2,$$we have$$P(Z\le\Bbb E Z)=P\left(x\le\frac{\Bbb E Z}{1-\Bbb E Z}\right)=\frac{1}{\ln 2}-1.$$

Comment: Shouldn't for EZ b e $x*( [x-\ln(1+x)]_0^1),$ , I think you have missed  x in the forumula EZ=$x f_{Z}(x)$ where  $f_{Z} $ is the derivative of Z

Comment: @Steffen No: the mean is $\int_0^1z(x)f_X(x)dx$. You could alternatively write it as $\int_0^1zdx=\int_0^{1/2}zx^\prime dz=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{zdz}{(1-z)^2}$, which still gives my answer.